# How to find and replace double quotes in R data frame

Tags: r, quotes, gsub

I have a data frame that looks like this (sorry, I can't replicate the actual data frame with code as the double quotes don't show up. Vx are variables):

```
V1, V2, V3, V4
home,   15, "grand",    terminal,
"give", 32, "cuz",  good,
"miles",    5,  "before",   ten,
yes,    45, "sorry,"    fine
```

Question: how I might be able to fix the double quote issue for my entire data frame that I've imported using the read.csv function, where all the double quotes are removed?

What I'm looking for is the excel or word equivalent of FIND + REPLACE: Find the double quote, and replace with nothing.

Notes:
1) I've confirmed it's a data frame by running is.data.frame() function
2) The actual data frame has hundreds of columns, so going through each one and declaring the type of column it is isn't feasible
3) I tried using the following, and it didn't work: `as.data.frame(sapply(my_data, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)))`
4) I confirmed that this isn't a simple print issue by testing using  sql on the the data frame. It won't find columns in double quotes unless I use LIKE instead of =

Thanks in advance!

7/7/15 EDIT 01: as requested from @alexforrence, here is the d(put) output for a couple of columns:

billing_first_name                           billing_last_name billing_company
3                                                                                                              NA
4                                                       Peldi                                  Guilizzoni              NA
5                                                                                                              NA
6                                              "James Andrew"                                       Angus              NA
7                                                                                                              NA
8                                                        Nova                                     Spivack              NA

Comment: You can give us a subset of the data.frame by using `dput()`, eg. `dput(head(df))`. Then paste the output as an edit to your question. Or for fewer columns, `dput(head(df[, 1:n]))`, n being the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `stringr`. Note that purely numerical columns will be character columns afterwards. It's not clear to me from your description whether there are purely numerical columns. If there are then you'd probably want to treat them separately, or alternatively convert back into numbers afterwards.

```
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
df <- data.frame(V1=c("home", "\"give\"", "\"miles\"", "yes"),
           V2=c(15, 32, 5, 45),
           V3=c("\"grand\"", "\"cuz\"", "\"before\"", "\"sorry\""),
           V4=c("terminal", "good", "ten", "fine"))
df
##        V1 V2       V3       V4
## 1    home 15  "grand" terminal
## 2  "give" 32    "cuz"     good
## 3 "miles"  5 "before"      ten
## 4     yes 45  "sorry"     fine

df %>% mutate_each(funs(str_replace_all(., "\"", "")))
##      V1 V2     V3       V4
## 1  home 15  grand terminal
## 2  give 32    cuz     good
## 3 miles  5 before      ten
## 4   yes 45  sorry     fine
```

Comment: @Claus Wilke: I want to avoid fixing the variables manually because there are hundreds of these cases, in just one file. I'm hoping to apply a function that can take of it to all the files I'm dealing with.

Comment: @ClausWilke: thanks for helping with this! What I mean by "3) I tried ... but it didn't work"is that the code ran fine, without errors, but the R object is still showing up with the same quotes in the same observations. I can't give you the full output of dput(head(df)) because it's too long and I run out of characters. How about if I give you some where I notice this issue? Here's some: billing_address1 = c(NA, 
    "\"504 Lavaca\"", NA, NA, NA, "\"60 Hurontario St.\""), billing_address2 = c(NA, 
    "\"Suite 1000\"", NA, NA, NA, "\"Suite 201\""),....class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that some of the observations are strings with characters between them? In this case, spaces? I noticed that pattern in this data.

Comment: I'm sorry, until you provide a complete and reproducible description of your problems I can't help any further.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the double quotes using `nchar()`.

```
a <- ""
nchar(a)==0
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above I ran into a very strange problem. Using the tips I wrote this very short program:

```
setClass("char.with.deleted.quotes")
setAs("character", "char.with.deleted.quotes", 
      function(from) as.character(gsub('„',"xxx", as.character(from), fixed = TRUE)))


TMP = read.csv2("./test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", dec=",",
                colClasses = c("character","char.with.deleted.quotes"))

temp <- gsub('„', "xxx", TMP$Name, fixed=TRUE)
print(temp)
```

with the Output:

```
> source('test.R')
[1] "This is some „Test" "And another „Test" 
[1] " "
Number               Name
1    X-23 This is some „Test
2 K-33.01  And another „Test
```

which reads the dummy csv:

```
Number;Name
X-23;This is some „Test
K-33.01;And another „Test
```

My goal is to get rid of this double quote before the word Test. However this so far does not work. And this is because of this double quote.

If instead I choose to replace a different part of the character it does work with either read.csv2 and the above definition of a class or directly with gsub saving it into the temp variable.

Now what is really strange is the following. After running the program I copied the two lines "temp <- gsub" and "print(temp)" manually into the command line:

```
> source('test.R')
[1] "This is some „Test" "And another „Test" 
[1] "This is some „Test" "And another „Test" 
[1] " "
Number               Name
1    X-23 This is some „Test
2 K-33.01  And another „Test
> 
> temp <- gsub('„', "xxx", TMP$Name, fixed=TRUE)
> print(temp)
[1] "This is some xxxTest" "And another xxxTest"
```

This for whatever reason works and it does also work if I modify the data frame directly:

```
> TMP$Name <- gsub('„', "xxx", TMP$Name, fixed=TRUE)
> print(TMP)
Number                 Name
1    X-23 This is some xxxTest
2 K-33.01  And another xxxTest
```

But if I repeat this command in the program and run it again, it does not work. And I really have no idea why.